# Problem SamplingRateCalculatorList (00000283DDC3C0E0) : All classes are empty ! OTB + QGis

Tags: image-processing, classification, qgis

I use OTB (Orfeo Tool Box) in QGis for classification. When I use the `ImageTrainClassifier`  tool in a batch process, I have a problem for some images. Instead of returning a model in a xml/txt file format, it returns several files with those extensions : `.xml_rates_1`, `.xml_samples_1.dbf`, `.xml_samples_1.prj`, `.xml_samples_1.shp`, `.xml_samples_1.shx`, `.xml_stats_1` (I have the same files with txt instead of xml if I use txt file format as output).
During the execution of the algorithms, I have only one warning message :

```
(WARNING): file ..\Modules\Learning\Sampling\src\otbSamplingRateCalculatorList.cxx, line 99, SamplingRateCalculatorList (00000283DDC3C0E0): All classes are empty !
```

And after that :

```
(FATAL) TrainImagesClassifier: No samples found in the inputs!
```

The problem is that after that, I want to use `ImageClassifier`, that takes the model of `ImageTrainClassifier` in input, that I don’t have.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey Chouchou, welcome to SO! Don't hesitate to add formatting to all your future questions to add clarity. It can help distinguish basic text to code or important keywork. Have a look at this page to know all the possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hello Baptiste, thank you for your correction and advice. Have a nice day !